# Python. Какой функцией можно заменить данный алгоритм?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Какая функция заменит алгоритм? Желательно без подключения отдельной библиотеки, но если без вариантов, то Ок. Варианты с мутированием или без - без разницы

```
box = [10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10]
box_new = []
for num in box:
    if box_new.count(num) == 0:
        box_new.append(num)

> box_new = [10, 20]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
list(set(box))
```

делает **почти** то же самое что и данный алгоритм, но не в точности то же.
Он не сохраняет порядок добавления элементов.

```
>>> list(set([2,5,4,1,4,2,3,6]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

И в этом примере просто так совпало, что числа отсортированы по возрастанию, в общем случае порядок не гарантируется.

```
>>> list(set('25414236'))
['1', '5', '6', '4', '2', '3']
```

Начиная с версии 3.6 в CPython, а с версии 3.7 и в спецификации языка, словари гарантируют обход элементов в порядке добавления. Можно этим воспользоваться:

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys([2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 6]))
[2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 6]
>>> list(dict.fromkeys('25414236'))
['2', '5', '4', '1', '3', '6']
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно создать сет (коллекция уникальных элементов) и потом конвертировать его в список

```
box_new = list(set(box))
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, функция set() никак не связана с set, который выдает гугл при поиске "python set"?

Comment: Связана напрямую, она именно тот сет и создает. Так же как функция list() создает список (который list).